# Python Equivalent to Selenium Browser Drivers Ruby Gem and Nuget Package?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am in the process of creating a Python Selenium Framework having previously written frameworks in both C# and Ruby.

With both those languages while I could download and store the relevent Webdriver file somewhere on my machine and reference it to make the Webdriver work I generally would instead install the relevent Ruby Gem or C# Package meaning I didnt need to worry about updating the driver manually or remembering which directory I had it saved in.

Is there an equivalent Python package I can install which will mean I dont need to worry about downloading and saving the file?

Comment: It's very interested to hear something like this, May I know why you continue to write the framework in various language?

Comment: different companies :)

Comment: You are writing framework for different companies?

Comment: No each framework was written while at a different company, so C# the first, 2nd used ruby, have just started at a 3rd who uses Python

Comment: Ah Okay thanks. I am currently writing a framework in Ruby so your question interested me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there an equivalent Python package I can install

The official release channel of the Python client bindings for Selenium is via PyPI (Python Package Index): https://pypi.org/project/selenium/

> which will mean I dont need to worry about 
>   downloading and saving the file?

I don't know what that means, but you can download a tar/zip from PyPI and install it yourself, or preferably you can use a package manager like Pip to install it (which will pull it from PyPI).

Answer (score 0):

Coming from Ruby, I had the same question. I was able to find binaries for chrome and phantomjs. I assume more can be found.

https://pypi.org/project/chromedriver-binary/
https://pypi.org/project/phantomjs-binary/

Comment: Please add an answer not a link to refer to as it might not work anytime